# iOS - UIStackView - zorder

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have this logic with a vertical `UIStackView`:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(v1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(v3)

//later 
stackView.insertArrangedSubview(v2, at: 1)
```

However, `v3` is below `v2`, so some overlapping badge icons are partially hidden. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adjusting the `zPosition` of a subview's layer (the larger the number, the higher it gets in the hierarchy):

```
subview.layer.zPosition = 1
```